# Equivalent of attributesByName core data method in Realm / Get properties/attributes of RLMObject

Tags: ios, core-data, properties, attributes, realm

In core data   if I had an entity as such

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

I can get its attributes by using the method

```
NSDictionary *entityAttributes = [entity attributesByName];
```

I was wondering what is the equivalent for the method `attributesByName` in Realm. I need something that will return the properties name and the property's type. Been searching in their documentation but can't seem to find a similar functionality available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation I think you can go this route starting from your `RLMObject`.

```
object.objectSchema.properties
```

This should give you an array of objects of type `RLMProperty`. You have the name in the `name` property of this class. Most of the information normally stored in the value part of kind `NSAttributeDescription` can be found in this class as well: e.g. `type`, etc.